# Issue with login endpont for Django REST Framework, The Registration was successful but the login doesn't authenticate, pls check LoginAPIView

Tags: django, api, django-rest-framework

## views.py - This is my authentication.views file

```
from rest_framework.views import APIView
from rest_framework.response import Response
from rest_framework import status
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate
from authentication.serializers import UserLoginSerializer, UserRegistrationSerializer

class UserRegistrationView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserRegistrationSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            user = serializer.save()
            return Response(
                {"msg": "Registration Successful"}, status=status.HTTP_201_CREATED
            )
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)

# The issue I'm having is at this point, all code seems write but still getting errors
class UserLoginView(APIView):
    def post(self, request, format=None):
        serializer = UserLoginSerializer(data=request.data)
        if serializer.is_valid(raise_exception=True):
            email = serializer.data.get('email')
            password = serializer.data.get('password')
            user = authenticate(password=password, email=email)

# This line above and below this comment
            if user is not None:
                return Response({"msg": "Login Successful"}, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
            else:
                return Response(
                    {
                        "errors": {
                            "non_field_errors": ["Email or Password is not valid"]
                        }
                    },
                    status=status.HTTP_404_NOT_FOUND
                )
        return Response(serializer.errors, status=status.HTTP_400_BAD_REQUEST)
```

## serializers.py - This is my authentication.serializers file

```
from rest_framework import serializers
from authentication.models import User

# Below are the UserRegistrationSerializer and UserLoginSerializer
class UserRegistrationSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
    password2 = serializers.CharField(style={"input_type": "password"}, write_only=True)
```

```
    class Meta:
        model = User
        fields = ["email", "username", "password", "password2"]
        extra_kwargs = {"password": {"write_only": True}}
```

```
    def validate(self, attrs):
        password = attrs.get("password")
        password2 = attrs.get("password2")
        if password != password2:
            raise serializers.ValidationError(
                "Password and Confirm Password does not match"
            )
        return attrs
```

```
def create(self, validated_data):
    return User.objects.create_user(**validated_data)
```

class UserLoginSerializer(serializers.ModelSerializer):
email = serializers.EmailField(max_length=100)
class Meta:
model = User
fields = ["email", "password"]

## urls.py for authenticaion app not root url file

## Below is the urls.py file

```
from django.urls import path
from . views import UserRegistrationView, UserLoginView
urlpatterns = [
    path('register/', UserRegistrationView.as_view(), name="register"),
    path('login/', UserLoginView.as_view(), name="login")
]
```

### Thanks for the review

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After authentication you must login the user as well.

```
from django.contrib.auth import authenticate, login
user = authenticate(password=password, email=email)
if user:
    login(request, user)
```

https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/topics/auth/default/#django.contrib.auth.login